# jquery Image gallery with an overlay, can't get the correct url on click because of the overlay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

im trying to make a flexbox image gallery popup onclick. Almost everything works, but I have trouble getting the url of the correct image. My code get the url only of the first image, no matter which image I click. Can someone help me and point out with what Im doing wrong?
Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".image-overlay").click(function() {

    var url = $('.content img').attr('src');
    $(".modal").css("display", "block");
    $(".close").css("display", "block");
    $('#img01').attr('src', url);
  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".image-overlay").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  });

  $(".image-overlay").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "0");
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(".modal").css("display", "none");
  });

});
```

```css
.gallery {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 0 5%;
}

.gallery-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gallery-column1 {
  -ms-flex: 18%;
  /* IE10 */
  flex: 18%;
  max-width: 18%;
  padding: 0 0.8em;
}

.gallery-column2 {
  -ms-flex: 24.7%;
  /* IE10 */
  flex: 24.7%;
  max-width: 24.7%;
  padding: 0 0.8em;
}

.gallery-column3 {
  -ms-flex: 31.2%;
  /* IE10 */
  flex: 31.2%;
  max-width: 31.2%;
  padding: 0 0.8em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .gallery-column1,
  .gallery-column2,
  .gallery-column3 {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.gallery-column1 img {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-column2 img {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-column3 img {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding: 1%;
  /* Location of the box */
  top: 20%;
  width: 320px;
  /* Full width */
  height: auto;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: -2%;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Overlay 8*/

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content .image-overlay {
  background: rgba(114, 208, 223, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 8%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-container">

  <div class="gallery-column1">
    <div class="content img1">
      <div class="image-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <img id="myImg" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery1.png">


    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    </div>

    <div class="content img4">
      <div class="image-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <img id="myImg4" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery4.png">
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="gallery-column2">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="image-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <img id="myImg2" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery2.png">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="image-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon4" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <img id="myImg5" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery5.png">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="gallery-column3">

    <div class="content">
      <div class="image-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <img id="myImg3" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery3.png">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="image-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon6" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <img id="myImg6" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery6.png">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

or my codepen url: https://codepen.io/christmastrex/pen/mdVzXMd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Elka,  your issue is in this line:

```
var url= $('.content img').attr('src');
```

Inside the event the keyword **this** refers to the current **image-overlay**. Said that, in order to find the image you need to select the [next img](https://api.jquery.com/next/) object.
Hence your code will be:

```
var url= $(this).next('img').attr('src');
```

The snippet:

```js
$(".image-overlay").click(function(){
    var url= $(this).next('img').attr('src');
    $(".modal").css("display","block");
    $(".close").css("display","block");
    $('#img01').attr('src', url);
});
$(".image-overlay").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
});

$(".image-overlay").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css("opacity", "0");
});
$(".close").click(function(){
    $(".modal").css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
.gallery{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top:5%;
    padding: 0 5%;
}


.gallery-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;

}

.gallery-column1 {
    -ms-flex: 18%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 18%;
    max-width: 18%;
    padding: 0 0.8em;
}

.gallery-column2 {
    -ms-flex: 24.7%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 24.7%;
    max-width: 24.7%;
    padding: 0 0.8em;
}

.gallery-column3 {
    -ms-flex: 31.2%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 31.2%;
    max-width: 31.2%;
    padding: 0 0.8em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .gallery-column1, .gallery-column2, .gallery-column3 {
        -ms-flex: 100%;
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}


.gallery-column1 img {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
.gallery-column2 img {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
.gallery-column3 img {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding: 1%; /* Location of the box */
    top: 20%;
    width: 320px; /* Full width */
    height: auto; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}



.close {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: -2%;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Overlay 8*/

.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content .image-overlay {
    background: rgba(114,208,223,0.8);
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 8%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gallery" id="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-container">
        <div class="gallery-column1">
            <div class="content img1">
                <div class="image-overlay">
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <img id="myImg" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery1.png">
            </div>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            </div>
            <div class="content img4">
                <div class="image-overlay">
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <img id="myImg4" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery4.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-column2">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="image-overlay">
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <img id="myImg2" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery2.png">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="image-overlay">
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon4" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <img id="myImg5" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery5.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-column3">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="image-overlay">
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <img id="myImg3" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery3.png">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="image-overlay">
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon6" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <img id="myImg6" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery6.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the following line in your js

```
var url= $('.content img').attr('src');
```

to

```
var url = $(this).siblings('img').attr('src');
```

So you get the image that is the sibling of the clicked `.image-overlay`

```js
/*var myVar = document.querySelectorAll('.content img');
var mySrc="";

for (var i = 0; i < myVar.length; i++) {
    mySrc = myVar[i].getAttribute('src');
  //alert(mySrc);
  
  
}*/

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".image-overlay").click(function() {

    var url = $(this).siblings('img').attr('src');
    $(".modal").css("display", "block");
    $(".close").css("display", "block");
    $('#img01').attr('src', url);
  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".image-overlay").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  });

  $(".image-overlay").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "0");
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(".modal").css("display", "none");
  });

});
```

```css
.gallery {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 0 5%;
}

.gallery-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gallery-column1 {
  -ms-flex: 18%;
  /* IE10 */
  flex: 18%;
  max-width: 18%;
  padding: 0 0.8em;
}

.gallery-column2 {
  -ms-flex: 24.7%;
  /* IE10 */
  flex: 24.7%;
  max-width: 24.7%;
  padding: 0 0.8em;
}

.gallery-column3 {
  -ms-flex: 31.2%;
  /* IE10 */
  flex: 31.2%;
  max-width: 31.2%;
  padding: 0 0.8em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .gallery-column1,
  .gallery-column2,
  .gallery-column3 {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.gallery-column1 img {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-column2 img {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-column3 img {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding: 1%;
  /* Location of the box */
  top: 20%;
  width: 320px;
  /* Full width */
  height: auto;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: -2%;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Overlay 8*/

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content .image-overlay {
  background: rgba(114, 208, 223, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 8%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery" id="gallery">

  <div class="gallery-container">

    <div class="gallery-column1">
      <div class="content img1">
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <img id="myImg" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery1.png">

      </div>

      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      </div>

      <div class="content img4">
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <img id="myImg4" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery4.png">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="gallery-column2">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <img id="myImg2" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery2.png">
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon4" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <img id="myImg5" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery5.png">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="gallery-column3">

      <div class="content">
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <img id="myImg3" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery3.png">
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="image-overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-search-plus gallery-icon6" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <img id="myImg6" src="http://elkatesthosting-com.stackstaging.com/mountains/images/gallery6.png">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Nico! I was not aware of siblings() as well. This works great too!